# Android upload folder filtered files

Tags: android, file-upload, filter, directory

Im try to upload all txt files from download folder in sdcard
I use file filter with ("txt")
But the app doesnt upload any txt file
I try the app without the file filter and upload successful one txt file but i want to upload all files
What is the wrong in my code... Why the app doesn't upload filtered files??
How to get filtered file to upload?

This my MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle      savedInstanceState)
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    uploadFile(sourceFileUri);}

public static   String sourceFileUri ="/mnt/sdcard/downloads";




public static void main(String[] args){


    File dir =new File(sourceFileUri);
    FilenameFilter filter =new MyFileFilter();
    File[] files = dir.listFiles(filter);
    for(File f : files)System.out.println(f.getName());   

}






public void uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

    new UploadFileAsync().execute("");}



private class UploadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {

            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

            if (sourceFile.isFile()) {

                try {
                    String upLoadServerUri = "http://sssssttttt.esy.es/uploaded.php?";

                    // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                        sourceFile);
                    URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                    // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                    conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                    conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE",
                                            "multipart/form-data");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                                            "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("bill", sourceFileUri);

                    dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"bill\";filename=\""
                                   + sourceFileUri + "\"" + lineEnd);

                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                    // create a buffer of maximum size
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                    // read file and write it into form...
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    while (bytesRead > 0) {

                        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                        bufferSize = Math
                            .min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0,
                                                         bufferSize);

                    }

                    // send multipart form data necesssary after file
                    // data...
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                                   + lineEnd);

                    // Responses from the server (code and message)
                int serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                    String serverResponseMessage = conn
                        .getResponseMessage();

                    if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                        // messageText.setText(msg);
                        //Toast.makeText(ctx, "File Upload Complete.",
                        //      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        // recursiveDelete(mDirectory1);

                    }

                    // close the streams //
                    fileInputStream.close();
                    dos.flush();
                    dos.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    // dialog.dismiss();
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                // dialog.dismiss();

            } // End else block


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // dialog.dismiss();

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}



}
```

And this MyFileFilter.class

```
public class MyFileFilter implements     FilenameFilter
{

@Override
public boolean accept(File directory, String fileName) {
    if (fileName.endsWith(".txt")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: I think using Volley would be better for this. You might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32262829/how-to-upload-file-using-volley-library-in-android) SO question helpful with uploading files to server

Comment: Ok but i just want to upload folder all files to server not one file...have u a link that help me?

Comment: Just give me a way to upload all files in folder like sdcard/folder    ..how to get all files in this folder? I can uplod one file from this folder but all no

Comment: Have you tried this [link]( http://stackoverflow.com/a/29197167/1055954)